# Mark EC2 unhealthy on high memory useage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, health-check

Im trying to put something into place to mark an EC2 instance unhealthy in an autoscaling group when it consumes < X memory.  I have seen some mentions of autoscaling policies based on memory consumption but I don't want the ASG to simply add more instances because the memory leak on the instance will persist. Instead when an instance uses more than 85% memory for example, I would like it marked unhealthy and let the ASG replace it.

Any tips?

The instances also have Datadog agent installed if that is useful.

Comment: Instead of waiting until they have gone "bad", you can just reboot/replace them on a regular interval proactively. I would call that a more classic approach :). If you wanted to go this route, just have your service's health check endpoint check its own memory and return non-200 if its over the limit. No adjustment to your ASG should be required if you're already using ELB healthchecks for your ASG.

Comment: Or a cronjob which checks the memory and reboot the instance which in turn will terminate the instance and you will have a new one. I have zero knowlege of datadog but I am sure there will be a way to send a command to the node when memory usage is < 85%.